# How to convert numpy arrays to standard TensorFlow format?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have two numpy arrays:

- One that contains captcha images
- Another that contains the corresponding labels (in one-hot vector format)

**I want to load these into TensorFlow so I can classify them using a neural network. How can this be done?**

What shape do the numpy arrays need to have?

Additional Info - My images are 60 (height) by 160 (width) pixels each and each of them have 5 alphanumeric characters. Here is a sample image:

[image: sample image.]

Each label is a 5 by 62 array.

Answer (score 59):

You can use `tf.convert_to_tensor()`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
data_np = np.asarray(data, np.float32)

data_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(data_np, np.float32)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  
print(data_tf.eval())

sess.close()
```

Here's a link to the documentation for this method:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor

Answer (score 8):

You can use [tf.pack](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pack) ([tf.stack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) in TensorFlow 1.0.0) method for this purpose. Here is how to pack a random image of type `numpy.ndarray` into a `Tensor`:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
random_image = np.random.randint(0,256, (300,400,3))
random_image_tensor = tf.pack(random_image)
tf.InteractiveSession()
evaluated_tensor = random_image_tensor.eval()
```

UPDATE: to convert a Python object to a Tensor you can use [tf.convert_to_tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) function.

Comment: there is no tf.pack

Comment: In the parantheses right aftet `tf.pack` I have mentioned that you should use `tf.stack` in newer versions if TensorFlow!

Answer (score 6):

You can use placeholders and feed_dict.

Suppose we have numpy arrays like these:

```
trX = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101) 
trY = 2 * trX + np.random.randn(*trX.shape) * 0.33
```

You can declare two placeholders:

```
X = tf.placeholder("float") 
Y = tf.placeholder("float")
```

Then, use these placeholders (X, and Y) in your model, cost, etc.:
    model = tf.mul(X, w) ... Y ...
    ...

Finally, when you run the model/cost, feed the numpy arrays using feed_dict:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
.... 
    sess.run(model, feed_dict={X: trY, Y: trY})
```

Comment: does this method allow me to use the in built tensor flow functions such as next batch?

Comment: @KeshavChoudhary next batch in MNIST? Sure, but you need to modify a bit for your dataset.

Comment: I want to build a dataset like MNIST but with my own images, I am a beginner to TensorFlow and neural networks. What is the easiest way to create a dataset like MNIST so I can follow the basic tutorial ?