# how to convert numpy array to keras tensor

Tags: python, numpy, keras

When using the keras model to do predict, I got the error below

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'

The reason is that the weights is numpy array, not tensor.
So how to convert numpy array to keras tensor?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor)?

Comment: Thank you,  Bazingaa. I am using Keras. Is there a way for keras tensor?

Comment: Ok, I was just trying to Google on your behalf for this problem. Perhaps try [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6045) using `.variable`

Comment: Thank you, Bazingaa.  It does not work.

Comment: hi, can you provide a little more context?  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you can find some good suggestions to help us help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926140/how-to-convert-numpy-arrays-to-standard-tensorflow-format ?

Answer (score 19):

In Tensorflow it can be done the following way:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = K.constant(a)
print(b)

# <tf.Tensor 'Const_1:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32>

print(K.eval(b))

# array([1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32)
```

In raw keras it should be done replacing `import tensorflow.keras.backend as K` with `from keras import backend as K`.

Comment: A variable isn't the same as a tensor according to Keras's documentation.
<code>
>>> keras_var = K.variable(np_var)` <br>
>>> K.is_keras_tensor(keras_var)  # A variable is not a Tensor.<br>
False<br>
>>> keras_placeholder = K.placeholder(shape=(2, 4, 5))<br>
>>> K.is_keras_tensor(keras_placeholder)  # A placeholder is a Tensor.<br>
True<br>
</code>

Comment: You are right, I have just updated my answer to use K.constant() instead of K.variable(), it returns a tensor instead of a variable as print() says

Comment: This is just perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 5):

To convert numpy array to tensor,

```
import tensor as tf
#Considering y variable holds numpy array
y_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.int64)
```

#You can use any of the available datatypes that suits best - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/DType

Comment: also you can use `import tensorflow as tf`