# how to convert keras tensor to numpy array

Tags: keras, tensor

```
input_feats = Input(shape=([fc_feats.shape[0]]))
def lam_reshape(inputs):
    return inputs
fc_feats_new = Lambda(lam_reshape)(input_feats)
fc_feats_new = K.reshape(fc_feats_new, [10, int(fc_feats_new.shape[1])])
fc_feats_new = sess.run(fc_feats_new)
```

got error:
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_54' with dtype float and shape [?,2048]

Comment: You have a very similar question from yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816938/how-to-convert-numpy-array-to-keras-tensor  Its better to update your question with new information than just asking a new one.

Comment: And secondly, what exactly are you trying to achieve with this code? You cannot evaluate a layer without an input.

Comment: Thanks  Matias, so firstly the shape is (2048, ), I want to reshape it to (10, 2048), then convert it to numpy array.

Comment: You can't reshape (2048) into (10, 2048), because 2048 is not equal to 10 * 2048, and anyways you could do that in numpy, no need for kera to do this. As I said before, you can't compute outputs of layers without inputs.