# How can I print fllaten Layers Output in CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I use a two path CNN for image processing. I want to print the Output of flatten layer. but when I want to print the output of flatten layer i am encountering this error:

> None Traceback (most recent call last):

> extracted_features = model.layers32

> File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 440, in **call**
> self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)

> File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 285, in assert_input_compatibility
> str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '

> ValueError: Layer flatten_39 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. Full input: [array([[[[0.51611316, 0.39746055, 0.5936753 ],
> [0.13327277, 0.34352553, 0.7586124 ],
> [0.99989164, 0.43303576, 0.5733409 ],
> ...,
> [0.05266873, 0.37530503, 0.12953256],
> [0.2471831 , 0.71032923, 0.25836825],
> [0.90023595, 0.96091986, 0.3706109 ]],

```
    [[0.14299522, 0.1676571 , 0.55554783],
     [0.01679909, 0.32093376, 0.8943776 ],
     [0.53657365, 0.83452356, 0.1076134 ],
     ...,
     [0.77388775, 0.6101447 , 0.14687575],
     [0.47331956, 0.5162232 , 0.5501466 ],
     [0.8316039 , 0.12746046, 0.23557535]],

    [[0.745321  , 0.12560171, 0.43350193],
     [0.7007471 , 0.5507861 , 0.19451097],
     [0.55038804, 0.05661515, 0.03471742],
     ...,
     [0.70201683, 0.1263634 , 0.13524196],
     [0.24133243, 0.564834  , 0.64897084],
     [0.15477973, 0.9518493 , 0.5475725 ]],

    ...,

    [[0.8317609 , 0.5864187 , 0.48500198],
     [0.14422454, 0.05594445, 0.5835567 ],
     [0.67728573, 0.63966084, 0.18180694],
     ...,
     [0.5717842 , 0.41698074, 0.22059603],
     [0.9030291 , 0.51441693, 0.2996456 ],
     [0.9422357 , 0.03952885, 0.5567205 ]],

    [[0.28786188, 0.4799473 , 0.92904633],
     [0.08306517, 0.9738849 , 0.9621486 ],
     [0.06010618, 0.47993308, 0.5765873 ],
     ...,
     [0.8719943 , 0.43593037, 0.53257006],
     [0.11550295, 0.48797372, 0.66570866],
     [0.32191348, 0.88470393, 0.19814569]],

    [[0.39397806, 0.78230894, 0.41833642],
     [0.38489413, 0.43042594, 0.76435673],
     [0.94453263, 0.5084677 , 0.8752447 ],
     ...,
     [0.16410913, 0.45611975, 0.23094064],
     [0.6859947 , 0.57103187, 0.3729119 ],
     [0.7035603 , 0.72346485, 0.63314646]]]], dtype=float32)]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

Code:

```py
input_shape = (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, 3)

num_classes = 3

# Data
path = "D:/Datesets/4- Card/data"
modelName = '2_Class'
training_data_dir = path + "/training" # 500 * 2
validation_data_dir = path + "/validation" # 100 * 2
test_data_dir = path + "/test" # 150
MODEL_FILE = modelName+ '-Vgg&ResnetBachSize'+ str(BATCH_SIZE)+ 'Epoch'+ str(EPOCHS)+ '.h5'

input1 = modelBuilder.defineInput()
input2 = modelBuilder.defineInput()

# First Path Of Training
finput1=modelBuilder.configInitialModel(input1)           finput2=modelBuilder.configInitialModel(input2)  
                                                          
output=modelBuilder.concatinateflattenInputs(finput1,finput2)

model=modelBuilder.makeModel(input1, input2, output) #(input1, input2, output)
print(model.summary())

img = np.random.random((1, 200, 200, 3)).astype("float32")

extracted_features = model.layers[32](img)

extracted_features = model.layers[33](img)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are facing this issue because you are passing a numpy array to the layer (check the error message). Could you try transforming the numpy array to a tensor?

Something like

```
img = torch.tensor(img)
extracted_features = model.layers[32](img)
```

If you are working with keras, the step would look [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816938/how-to-convert-numpy-array-to-keras-tensor)

**Edit**
Copied from the answer above -

For keras/tensorflow, try this

```
import tensor as tf
#Considering y variable holds numpy array
y_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.int64)
```

Comment: img = tf.tensor(img)

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'tensor'

Comment: `import tensor as tf`    
`#Considering y variable holds numpy array`  
`y_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.int64)`  

Try this

Comment: I used the following command to display and print the output of the felt layer. However, it is not possible to display and print the output of this layer and >Tensor("flatten_1_1/Reshape:0", shape=(1, 120000), dtype=int64)
is displayed. I want to print values of this Layer

Comment: So is it working now? That's good. What is happening is that the you are receiving the object name when you're trying to print the value. I'd suggest you to read the documentation and go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow) for the solution.